# Display Content based on situation (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am creating an app using Xamarin Forms. I have a MainTab page that displays all the 4 tabs. There is one specific tab call Me tab.

As of now the Me Tab displays the user's profile. However, when the user is not logged in, it my UserLogin page should be displayed instead. How do I do that in Xamarin forms?

Comment: Please do research and [look it up yourself](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48634/from-login-page-to-main-page) before asking on [so]. Also, best not to mention you need a solution urgently... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in various ways. If you're using a MVVM approach the most straight forward solution would be to set a binding in your viewmodel indicating user logging. Based on that you can set your 
tabbedPage.CurrentPage = TheTabPageYouWant.
If you're using codebehind, just use in your ;

```
public bool UserLogged
{
get { return _userLogged; }
set
{
_userLogged = value;
if (_userLogged)
{
tabbedPage.CurrentPage = UserProfilePage.    
return;
}
tabbedPage.CurrentPage = LogInPage.
}
```

I strongly recommend any Xamarin.Forms book and MVVM techniques for you.
Don't hesitate to ask any further questions.

Comment: Then what if the UserLogin page is not part of the tabs? It only requires to be shown as a pop up page when a button is click? @TolgaKartal

Comment: Then the solution is the same :) instead of tabbedPage.CurrentPage just use Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();

Comment: Wow Thanks so much! :) @TolgaKartal

Comment: Hi ShahanazSK if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.